# Как лучше хранить изображения на диске?

Tags: php, база-данных, изображения, файловая-система, хранение-данных

Делаю сайт, где будут посты с изображениями. 1 изображение на 1 пост. Загружать все эти изображения в одну директорию, думаю, будет неправильно.

Нашел видео, где автор сделал подкаталоги — `1`, `2`, `3` и хранил по 200 изображений в каждом из них, и если последний каталог заполнен, скрипт создает следующий новый каталог (`4`). Правильный ли это подход? Есть ли другие способы? Как организовать структуру папок для хранения этих изображений?

Comment: есть достаточно простое допущение, создавать новую папку раз день или раз в час, в зависимости от того, какая скорость наполнения...

Comment: Хранить лучше все таки на диске. при этом помнить, что файловая система начинает тормозить, если в одной папке более 1000 файлов (ориентировочно). поэтому делают многоуровневую структуру с вложенностью 2 или 3. Названия каталогов может зависеть например от id файла в БД или от контрольной суммы самого файла (например md5).

Comment: Например в одном проекте у меня берется md5 от файла в base64. Первая буква дает корневую папку, вторая следующую. Файл с md5 = j1ZFj2FvjGlUNuTbuflyoA лежит в `/j/1/j1ZFj2FvjGlUNuTbuflyoA`. тут у нас максимум 64 папки на уровне и того 4096 папок, для миллиона файлов это порядка 244 файлов на папку. А например прокси squid кеш хранит в 2х уровневой иерархии по 256 папок на уровень, называет по 2 шестнадцетиричные цифры, т.е. /12/34/123456aaaa... итого 65536 папок

Comment: А с подкаталогами 1,2,3 по 200 изображений я вижу 2 минуса: вычисление имени папки из скажем id файла требует деления на 200, что несколько неудобно. лучше делить на степень двойки, причем сдвигом. если файлов действительно много то папок на корню будет так же очень много, для миллиона файлов это уже 5000 папок, что многовато. все таки двухуровневая система для большого количества лучше подходит и масштабируется (у всяких там фейсбуков не удивлюсь если для каждой папки первого уровня отдельный сервер хранения стоит)

Comment: Ну и применять id или md5 выбор опять же за вами. по id быстро вычислять положение проще и хранить md5 не надо. Зато в случае md5 сколько бы раз один файл нам не заливали храним мы только 1 копию (но помним, что теоретически возможны коллизии, так что может еще размер проверять и включать в имя)

Comment: храню по md5, 2 символа 0-F на уровень: `/45/E8/78454...`

Comment: @Mike Спасибо большое!